# Can't read wavefront file

Tags: c++, file, opengl, scanf, strcmp

I've a problem with this code:

```
    void readObj(const char* fName, std::vector<Vector3> &tempVertex, std::vector<Face3>  &tempFaces){
    FILE* file;
    file = fopen(fName, "r");
    if (file == 0)
        printf("#ERROR# can't open file!");
    else{
        while(true){
         char lineHeader[1000];
         int res = fscanf(file, "%s", lineHeader);
         if (res == EOF)
             break;
         else if (strcmp(lineHeader, "v ") == 0){
             Vector3 v;
             fscanf(file, "%f %f %f\n", &v.x, &v.y, &v.z);
             cout<<"tempVertex.push_back(v)";
             tempVertex.push_back(v);
         }
         else if (strcmp(lineHeader, "f ") == 0){
             Face3 f;
             fscanf(file, "%d %d %d", &f.a, &f.b, &f.c);
             cout<<"tempFaces.push_back(f)";
             tempFaces.push_back(f);
         }
         else{
            fscanf(file, "/n");
            cout<<"Nothing in this line!\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here I use it:

```
private: System::Void readFile(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         vector<Vector3> test;  
         vector<Face3> ftest;
         reading::readObj("Text.txt", test, ftest);
     }
```

Test.txt:

```
    v 1.0f 2.0f 3.0
    f 1 2 3
```

And it produce only:

```
    Nothing in this line! (x8)
```

instead of tempVertex.push_back(v) and tempFaces.push_back(f).

Comment: Why are you using C functions in a C++ program? Use streams and `std::string`.

Comment: Also, why are you scanning for `"/n"`? And for the `"f"` lines, don't forget to add the trailing whitespace in the `fscanf` format.

Comment: Your else is missing `{}`

Comment: I just started a month ago with c++ and didn't know how to skip a line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a more C++ idiomatic solution:

```
void readObj(const std::string& fName,
             std::vector<Vector3>& tempVertex,
             std::vector<Face3>& tempFaces)
{
    std::ifstream file(fName);

    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(file, line))
    {
        std::istringstream iss(line);

        char type;
        if (iss >> type)
        {
            if (type == 'v')
            {
                Vector3 v;
                if (iss >> v.x >> v.y >> v.z)
                    tempVertex.push_back(v);
            }
            else if (type == 'f')
            {
                Face3 f;
                if (iss >> f.a >> f.b >> f.c)
                    tempFaces.push_back(v);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

References:

- [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)
- [`std::ifstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream)
- [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream)
- [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

---

As for your current code (as posted in the question) a big problem is this:

```
strcmp(lineHeader, "v ")
/* here -------------^ */
```

The string `lineHeader` only contains the `"v"` or `"f"`, not the trailing space.

Comment: It says: ERROR no operator ">>" matches these operands

Comment: Do I have to include something?

Comment: @user2894128 On what line? And please edit your question to include the `Vector3` and `Face3` structures.

Comment: @user2894128 Yes you have to include some header files. Follow the reference links at the end to see which ones.

Comment: std::istringstream iss(line);

Comment: solved(It says: ERROR no operator ">>" matches these operands)

Comment: 'if (iss >> v.x >> v.y >> v.z){
 tempVertex.push_back(v);
 printf("%f %f %f", v.x, v.y, v.z);
 }'

Comment: @user2894128 It's because there's an error in the input file. Look at the values for the `v` line, two of them have an `f` appended to them which they shouldn't have. If those `'f'` characters are always there for the first and second (but curiously not for the third) then you have to read that as well, but it can be thrown aray.